# ugettext_lazy not working in model choices when using format functions

Tags: django, localization

I am trying to translate choices from my models.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _    

GRID_LEVEL = [(None, 'null')]
for r in range(-15, 15):
   text = _('Level %s') % str(r)
   GRID_LEVEL.append((str(r), text))
```

I have tried brackets and %(var)s syntax but still no luck. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this. Concatenation, formatting etc. doesn't work on lazy objects. I instead used `string_concat` for Django 1.10 which returns a lazy object.

```
from django.utils.translation import string_concat, ugettext_lazy as _

GRID_LEVEL = [(None, 'null')]
for r in range(-15, 15):
   text = string_concat(_('Level '), str(r))
   GRID_LEVEL.append((str(r), text))
```